# Remove specfic reference created from file

Tags: excel, vba, reference

I put together the following VBA to add a reference to a workbook.

```
Sub Add_Reference()

Dim vbProj As Object

Set vbProj = ActiveWorkbook.VBProject

vbProj.References.AddFromFile "C:\User\documents\Master_file.xlsm"

CleanUp:
Set vbProj = Nothing

End Sub
```

I thought I would be ale to do the same to `remove` by switching out the `AddFromfile` with `Remove` as follows:

```
Sub Remove_Reference()

Dim vbProj As Object

Set vbProj = ActiveWorkbook.VBProject

vbProj.References.Remove "C:\User\documents\Master_file.xlsm"

CleanUp:
Set vbProj = Nothing

End Sub
```

When I run `Remove_Reference` I get a `Type mismatch` error on the `vbProj.References.Remove "C:\User\documents\Master_file.xlsm"` line.  Im guessing I need to call it something else but I am not sure what it should be.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You are confusing with the datatypes.

`AddFromFile` accepts a `string` parameter which is the full file path.
`Remove` on the other hand asks for `Reference` type as parameter. Hence the type mismatch error.

You need to loop, match and then remove the reference.

---

```
Sub test()

    Dim refs            As Object 'VBIDE.References
    Dim ref             As Object 'VBIDE.Reference
    Dim strRefPath      As String

    strRefPath = "C:\User\documents\Master_file.xlsm"

    Set refs = ThisWorkbook.VBProject.References

    For Each ref In refs

        Debug.Print ref.Name & "=> " & ref.FullPath

        If ref.FullPath = strRefPath Then
            Debug.Print "removing :" & ref.FullPath
            refs.Remove ref
            Exit For
        End If

    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, but It's too long to leave as a comment.

Try the code below to help you debug the property of the `Reference` you want to remove.

Loop thorough all `vbProj.References` and use `Deubg.print` to see the exact property of the `Reference` you want to remove.

```
Sub ProjRef()

Dim vbProj As Object
Dim i As Long

Set vbProj = ActiveWorkbook.VBProject

With vbProj.References
    For i = 1 To .Count  ' loop through references

        Debug.Print .Item(i).Description
        Debug.Print .Item(i).Name
        Debug.Print .Item(i).FullPath

        ' add here your If to check the reference you want to remove

    Next
End With

End Sub
```